# Show name of the tag and not commit message in Blue Ocean

Tags: jenkins, tags, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I have a problem, currently Open Blue Ocean shows the commit message, is it possible to show the name of the tag?
Thank you.

[open blue ocean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJXbA.png)